# jscrollpane styling the arrows

Tags: jquery, coding-style, jscrollpane

I'm implementing the jScroll pane jQuery script (from http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com ) on a page under development, and want to style it to suit the design of the page:

- for some reason the scroll area doesn't span to the full text of the div. don't know what could be the problem?
  *(solved with making a fallback font for the @font-face loaded font, and making the font-size-adjust in css)*
- I'm using both arrows on bottom, but I would like to resize the complete arrow area so that it's more loose
- also, I would like to make the disabled arrows grey, and have prepared the images, but I don't know how to make the selection to .jspDisabled class so it shows the appropriate images and not the same image for both.

The page:
http://baksagaspar.com/francesco-work/

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember, jScrollPane uses CSS for the arrow images.

Just replace the `background-image` property on the style for the classes: `.jspArrowDown` and `.jspArrowUp`.

For disabled, make sure the `backgroud-image` for `.jspArrowUp .jspDisabled` is set to important.

Example:

```
.jspArrowUp {
  background-image: url(upArrow.jpg);
}

.jspArrowUp.jspDisabled {
  background-image: url(upArrowDisabled.jpg) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The !important solved the thing. 
And is it possible to enlarge the height of the arrows-area so that there is more spacing between the bottom and the bottom-arrow, and also more space between the two arrows? Or would it involve some serious fiddling with the jScrollPane's script?

Comment: Set a `margin-bottom` on the class `.jspArrow` will add padding between the top arrow and the bottom arrow, and between the bottom arrow and the bottom of the bar.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the `margin-bottom` moves the bottom arrow out of the view, because the height of the (both) arrows' area doesn't change (probably it would need also to shrink the scroll bar on top of it relative to as much it gets bigger).

Comment: To add space between the arrows you can set them to have a greater height in CSS but display the background image within the arrow div so that it has space around it...

Comment: Sorry I don't get it... When I set the height it also happens that the bottom arrow moves out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the scroll on the wrong div.

```
$('#text-content-in').jScrollPane( {
    showArrows: true,
    verticalArrowPositions: 'after',
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'after'
});
```

Comment: Sorry, your method didn't work out, the div was correct.
The problem was that the script counted wrongly the height of the div, because of the @font-face loaded font. Now I made a fallback font, and adjusted the font-size-adjust for the @font-face font, and it works :-))
Any suggestions to the other two problems please?